# React: create number of (svg use) elements based on input field

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am starting with React and trying to make a dynamic svg: I'd like to 'bind' the numeric value of the input to the number of circles (`<use>`) shown on the canvas. However, the `{message}` state variable does not work in a `for` loop – I don't know how to create/modify the array. How could I render the `{sampleCircles}` dynamically? Thanks in advance.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Svg() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(0);
  let sampleCircleCopies = [
    <use href="#originalCircle" x="15" y="15" key="1" />,
    <use href="#originalCircle" x="30" y="30" key="2" />
  ];

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <svg className="p-0 border-2 mx-auto" width="400" height="400">
        <circle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r="10"
          id="originalCircle"
          style={{ fill: "orange" }}
        />

        {sampleCircleCopies}
      </svg>

      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          className="border-2 mt-2 p-1 rounded-xl"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={message}
        />
        <h2>Number of cloned circles: {message}</h2>

      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of JSX elements which react will render for you. I'd also use [`valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) instead of `value`. You can of course also embed the `map()` directly within the JSX.

```js
function Svg() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(0);
  const sampleCircleCopies = [...new Array(message)].map((_, i) => (
    <use href="#originalCircle" x={Math.floor(200 * Math.random())} y={Math.floor(50 * Math.random())} key={i} />
  ));
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg className="p-0 border-2 mx-auto" width="400" height="400">
        <circle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r="10"
          id="originalCircle"
          style={{ fill: "orange" }}
        />
        {sampleCircleCopies}
      </svg>
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          className="border-2 mt-2 p-1 rounded-xl"
          onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
          value={message}
        />
        <h2>Number of cloned circles: {sampleCircleCopies.length}</h2>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Svg/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> I've changed the code a bit to generate random circles every time the count increases in order to show that the code is working and you are getting however many circles you want.